# MapViewPlugin.kt: (168, 34): Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed

Tags: kotlin, flutter

Can't figure out how to fix it:

```
e:
/media/development/tools/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/map_view-0.0.14/android/src/main/kotlin/com/apptree
software/mapview/MapViewPlugin.kt: (168, 34): Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type Map<String, Any>?
```

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 1):

You can find a solution in [JTorrus's answer](https://github.com/apptreesoftware/flutter_google_map_view/issues/129#issuecomment-436954546) 
For lazy people I paste it there:)

1. Open the Android project and go to the MapView module, then select MapViewPlugin.kt inside the java folder (This should be the file path: /.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/map_view-0.0.14/android/src/main/kotlin/com/apptreesoftware/mapview/MapViewPlugin.kt)
2. If you are using Android Studio you will already see red warnings. Go to line 168 where you'll find val cameraDict = mapOptions["cameraPosition"] as Map
3. Change it to this val cameraDict = mapOptions!!["cameraPosition"] as Map

Now it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a variable of type `Map<String, Any>`? in MapViewPlugin.kt.

The question marks denotes that the variable is nullable and Kotlin forces you to think of the consequences before accessing the variable. Thus you need to either access it using a safe operator, ?, or the not-null assertion operator, !!.

The safe operator will not call the function / property if the variable is null and instead return null, the second will throw a `NullPointerException` if the variable is null when you try to access it (same as always happen in Java for example).

[Read more here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html).